# How to Execute command/macro, before "If-then" applied or after "If-then" applied?

Tags: excel, vba

```
'Membuat shortcut sheet untuk lebih pendek
'Make shortcut
Set po = Sheets("Print Out")
Dim awal, Akhir As Integer
Dim j As Long
'mencantumkan N6 & O6 menjadi value acuan
'Make N6 & O6 as main value print
awal = po.Range("N6").Value
Akhir = po.Range("O6").Value
j = 0
'menjalankan menu pilih printer
'Show up print dialog and set "normal" print area (w/o) condition
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
po.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$B$1:$L$57"
'perintah utama
'Main command to apply auto mass print
    For i = awal To Akhir
        With po
            .Range("M1").Value = i + 0 + j
            .Range("M2").Value = i + 1 + j
            .Range("M3").Value = i + 2 + j
            .Range("M4").Value = i + 3 + j
            .PrintPreview
            j = j + 3
        End With
'jika mendeteksi N/A atau sejenisnya perintah akan berhenti
'If found #N/A or #REF or any error loop will stop to prevent loop printing even data already reach limit
      If IsError(po.Range("C4")) Then Exit For
      If IsError(po.Range("C18")) Then
      po.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$B$1:$L$15"
      Exit For
'Jika M4 lebih besar dari batas akhir (O6) maka perintah akan terhenti
'If m4 > than O6 then print area will change and stop the loop (THIS IS THE PROBLEM)
      If po.Range("M4") + 2 > po.Range("O6") Then po.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$B$1:$L$43"
          If po.Range("M3") + 3 > po.Range("O6") Then po.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$B$1:$L$29"
            If po.Range("M2") + 4 > po.Range("O6") Then po.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$B$1:$L$15"
    Next i
```

The macro I created as above, but there is a problem that I cannot overcome.

Like the following line:

`If po.Range("M4") + 2 > po.Range("O6") Then po.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$B$1:$L$43"`

Basically, the code above will adjust the "printarea" if it has crossed the limit I have set, but I want to add an "Exit for" command to stop the loop after the "If-then" criteria is met.`

I already tried to make

```
If po.Range("M4") + 2 > po.Range("O6") Then 
po.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$B$1:$L$43
Exit for
```

but the "Exit for" code will run along with the printarea change, so my last page has not been printed yet. What I want is for the loop to stop after my last page is printed (where my last page will always be related to the "if then" above).

Comment: It is not clear for me what you want to achieve with your requested _Exit For_. _Exif For_ exits your for loop, mayby you searching for _next_ instead. Please consider to use an _If-ElseIf-Else_ instead of multiple _If_-Statements.

Comment: @Shrotter I basically want to be like this
`If po.Range("M4") + 2 > po.Range("O6") Then po.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$B$1:$L$43"` = true then the looping will stop afterwards

Comment: Which looping should stop? Your _for next_? Or your next _If_ statement should not executed and the _next i_ should executed?

Comment: @Shrotter looping for "for next"

Answer (score 1):

### `If...Then` and `Select Case`

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    'Membuat shortcut sheet untuk lebih pendek
    'Make shortcut
    
    ' Reference (set) the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' Reference (set) the worksheet.
    Dim po As Worksheet: Set po = wb.Worksheets("Print Out")
    
    With po
    
        'mencantumkan N6 & O6 menjadi value acuan
        'Make N6 & O6 as main value print
        Dim Awal As Long: Awal = .Range("N6").Value
        Dim Akhir As Long: Akhir = .Range("O6").Value
    
        'menjalankan menu pilih printer
        'Show up print dialog and set "normal" print area (w/o) condition
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
        .PageSetup.PrintArea = "$B$1:$L$57"
        
        Dim i As Long
        Dim j As Long
        
        'perintah utama
        'Main command to apply auto mass print
        For i = Awal To Akhir
            
            .Range("M1").Value = i + 0 + j
            .Range("M2").Value = i + 1 + j
            .Range("M3").Value = i + 2 + j
            .Range("M4").Value = i + 3 + j
            .PrintPreview
            j = j + 3
            
            'jika mendeteksi N/A atau sejenisnya perintah akan berhenti
            'If found #N/A or #REF or any error loop will stop to prevent loop printing even data already reach limit
            If IsError(.Range("C4")) Then
                ' do nothing!
            ElseIf IsError(.Range("C18")) Then
                .PageSetup.PrintArea = "$B$1:$L$15"
            Else
                'Jika M4 lebih besar dari batas akhir (O6) maka perintah akan terhenti
                'If m4 > than O6 then print area will change and stop the loop (THIS IS THE PROBLEM)
                Select Case .Range("O6").Value
                    ' This logic is wrong! All cases are the same:
                    ' .Range("M4") + 2 = .Range("M3") + 3 = .Range("M2") + 4
                    Case Is < .Range("M4").Value + 2: .PageSetup.PrintArea = "$B$1:$L$43"
                    Case Is < .Range("M3").Value + 3: .PageSetup.PrintArea = "$B$1:$L$29"
                    Case Is < .Range("M2").Value + 4: .PageSetup.PrintArea = "$B$1:$L$15"
                    Case Else
                        ' do nothing!?...
                        ' ... or e.g.:
                        'MsgBox "Something went wrong. Add more cases.", vbCritical
                End Select
            End If
        
        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you miss the ELSE statement and END IF.

```
If po.Range("M4") + 2 > po.Range("O6") Then 
    po.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$B$1:$L$4"
Else
    Exit for
End if
```

Comment: I'm already try this, but this code will stop the the loop before i can print all my cheque

Answer (score 0):

You can also use GOTO to get your program to continue from another place in your code. EXIT FOR will always forse your FOR loop to end.

```
If po.Range("M4") + 2 > po.Range("O6") Then 
    po.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$B$1:$L$4"
Else
    GOTO ContinueHere 
End if
' Code you want to skip

ContinueHere:
' Continues to code here  

NEXT
```